# jQuery Use a string selector for nextAll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been struggling to write a string selector representation of nextAll, something like this.

```
$('span:nextall(span.simple)');
```

instead of using

```
$('span').nextAll('span.simple');
```

Can the jQuery expression ":" be extended to do this?

Comment: The colon (`:`) is not a **jQuery** specific expression, but instead a **CSS Selector.** Therefore, you cannot do such a thing. What exactly does `nextAll` do that you are trying to replicate?

Comment: I was referring to the jQuery selection expression that jQuery provides, as explained here. http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/

Comment: Well if there is no `nextAll` or `nextall` extension, then it won't work. You would need to write a **custom** extension, as defined in that document you linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simpler solution for this by using a sibling selector.

```
$('span ~ span.simple');
```

Answer (score 0):

not very elegant but

https://jsfiddle.net/bdellinger/ejrvjn4h/2/

```
$( "span.third" ).nextAll().css( "color", "red" );
```

becomes

```
$( "span:gt("+$( "span" ).index( $('.third'))+")" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

Comment: 2nd expression does not have valid syntax. I was referring to a serialized string expression that could be persisted to a database.